# How to calculate present value of payouts

Tags: finance, compound-interest

If you purchased a savings plan where, starting today, you are required to invest \$10,000 a year at the start of every year for the next twenty years. After twenty years, the savings plan guarantees a return of \$5,000 every 6 months for the next forty years. Suppose that the effective interest rates are constant at 2% over the next sixty years. What is the present value of the payouts of the savings plan?

1. \$64,033.87
2. \$21,926.04
3. \$29,739.01
4. -\$29,018.00

I made minor tweaks to the formula here:
[PV formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBa98.jpg)

Where C = 5000, r = 2%, n = 40, I used PV = sum of Ci/(1+0.02/2)^2*ti. But I got \$91706.06.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.